# redirect for only admin module

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have the following code inside my `Admin Module.php`

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $application = $e->getApplication();
    $em = $application->getEventManager();
    if(!SystemUtils::isApiRequest()){
        $em->attach(\Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH, array($this,'initUser'),10000);
    }

}
public function initUser(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $isLoggedIn=false;
    // determined elsewhere
    $action = Pluto::registry('application_action');
    if($action!=='login' && !$isLoggedIn){
            $viewHelperManager = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('ViewHelperManager');
            $renderer = $viewHelperManager->getRenderer();
            $url = $renderer->plutourl('login');            
            $response = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('Response');
            $response->getHeaders()->clearHeaders()->addHeaderLine('Location', $url);
            $response->setStatusCode(302)->sendHeaders();
            exit();
    }
}
```

The problem is this is only supposed to activate when inside a page within the admin module and you are not logged in **but its operating for every request regardless of the module the code is inside**

I want to limit this check to just when accessing the admin module.

**Update**

```
$sm = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
    $router = $sm->get('router');
    $request = $sm->get('request');
    $matchedRoute = $router->match($request);
```

returns the admin controller class name which i can use but i want it for all of the admin controller classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the shared event manager to attach to events in a given name space. In the example below we attach to an event only for the current modules namespace.

```
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;

public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $app = $e->getApplication();
    $em  = $app->getEventManager()->getSharedManager();
    $sm  = $app->getServiceManager();

    $em->attach(__NAMESPACE__, MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH, function ($e) use ($sm) {
        /**
         * this will be triggered only by controlers in
         * this module/namespace...
         */
         $this->doSomething();
    });
}
```

You could add this inside your admin module and only this event will only be listened to for classes inside this module / namespace.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `MvcEvent` object!

If all controllers are under a single namespace, for instance `\Admin\Controller`:

```
$namespace = 'Admin\\Controller\\';
$matchController = $e->getRouteMatch()->getParam('controller');

if( $namespace === substr($matchController, 0, strlen($namespace))
{
     // check here if user is logged in.
}
else {
     // not an admin controller, do nothing.
}
```